# How can I set the value of column C as a string in my Google Visualization Query?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How can I tell the data from a Google Visualization Query that Column C is a string?  I can't find anywhere in the documentation options that shows me how to designate certain columns as strings or numbers.   It thinks column C is a number and ads another column in the column chart, when it's actually suppose to be set as a string.

Do I set it in query options or in the options for the column chart?
I added my code and pictures of the dashboard and datasheet.

Thanks!
Brandon

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a bar chart,
      // passes in the data and draws it.
      
      function drawDashboard() {
         var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/a/sleschool.org/spreadsheets/d/1TRcHxsLuunRUPgn-i-h3OcVvh0TNp_VhJrNBI3ulMlA/edit#gid=0');
      
      query.setQuery('select A,B,C');
      
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);
      }

      function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
          alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
          return;
        }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
        // Create a dashboard.
        
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var scoreSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
            containerId: 'filter_div',
            options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'Score'
               }
        });
        
        var rtiFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'CategoryFilter', 
            containerId: 'rtifilter_div',
            options: {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'RTI','ui': { 'labelStacking': 'vertical','allowTyping': true,'allowMultiple': true
               }
        }});

        // Create a Column Bar chart, passing some options
        var columnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'ColumnChart',
            containerId: 'chart_div',
            options: {
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            legend: 'right',
            title: 'Summative Assessment Data',
               }
        });
        
        // Define a table
        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'Table',
          dataTable: data,
          containerId: 'table_div',
          options: {
          width: '400px'
               }
         });
       
        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'ColumnChart',
        // so that the column chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        
        dashboard.bind([scoreSlider], [table, columnChart]);
        dashboard.bind([rtiFilter], [table, columnChart]);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
     <div id="dashboard_div">
    
     <h2>Summative Assessment Data</h2>
     
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <br />
     
      <div id="rtifilter_div"></div>
   
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="chart_div"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="table_div"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Data Sheet]
[image: Dashboard Output.]

Answer (score 0):

I've haven't built DataTables in this way before but you might try using [setColumnProperty](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_setColumnProperty).

I have no idea if type can be changed after it is created but it is worth a shot trying something like this:

```
data = response.getDataTable();
data.setColumnProperty(colIndex, "type", "string");
```